# Eclipse Juno - import perspectives from Indigo?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-indigo, eclipse-juno

I am running a new install of Eclipse Juno on the same project I used Eclipse Indigo with and noticed that it hasn't kept my perspectives - is there any way to import these?

Perspectives are not picked up with import/export preferences.

Comment: Eclipse 4.2 can't pick up the old perspectives from workbench.xml and transfer them to workbench.xmi.  See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=378811

Comment: @PaulWebster - thank you for the response. If you put this as an answer, I will accept this. Obviously I need to re-create my perspectives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer from @PaulWebster is correct.

> Eclipse 4.2 can't pick up the old perspectives from workbench.xml and
>   transfer them to workbench.xmi. See
>   bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=378811 – Paul Webster

Comment: A better quote would be "There is no hope of cross-translating the 3.x information into 4.x" as I try to switch from Indigo (3.7) to Luna (4.4)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to preserve your perspectives as well as other workspace settings from Indigo by using the Indigo workspace in Juno.

To do so, open Indigo and copy the path of the workspace by going to File -> Switch Workspace -> Other.

(It might be worth taking a backup of the Indigo workspace folder before using it in Juno.)

Now close Indigo, open Juno and switch to the above workspace by going to File -> Switch Workspace -> Other and pasting the path you copied from Indigo and pressing enter.

Juno shall restart and after that you should have all your perspectives.

Comment: It did not work for me - I am using Indigo and Juno in the same workspace already and have a bunch of custom perspectives I created while in Indigo.. I tried re-switching Juno to the same workspace and it did not pick up the custom workspaces. I confirmed that when I go into the Indigo I do see the custom workspaces and triply confirmed that they are really truly using the same workspace dir.

Comment: I can also see my perspectives defined in .metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.ui.workbench\workbench.xml